# Can't launch Jupyter Notebook on osx -

Tags: python, macos, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter on my macbook pro (10.10), using pip install jupyter, it completed sucessfully. However, when trying to run the

```
jupyter notebook
```

command - I get the following errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in 
       sys.exit(main())

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line   267, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",   line 591, in launch_instance
 app.initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
 return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1008, in initialize
  self.init_terminals()
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 908, in init_terminals
  from .terminal import initialize
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/terminal/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
 import terminado
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/terminado/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NullHandler'
```

Can you please advise..

```
per additional requested info

bash-3.2$ python --version 
Python 2.7.10
bash-3.2$ echo $PYTHONPATH

bash-3.2$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `which -a python`, `echo $PYTHONPATH` `python --version`

Comment: `bash-3.2$ python --version 
Python 2.7.10` ,                                                                                                       
`bash-3.2$ echo $PYTHONPATH
` , 
`bash-3.2$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

### Simpler installation with Anaconda

An alternative to using `pip` is [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).
It is great for installing scientific libraries such as Jupyter.

### Anaconda

Anaconda is a full distribution of about 200 libraries including Jupyter. Just install it with given instruction as user (not root) and you should be good to go.

### Miniconda

Miniconda is smaller. It includes Python and a few essential libraries. If Anconda seems to big, download and install Miniconda. Again, as user not as root.
Then, install Jupyter with:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Comment: 200 libraries - and some of them are not even broken! - Just joking, but I would be careful recommending anaconda as the perfect way for beginners at the moment. After all, there are broken packages, and understanding why things won't work can be rather cumbersome/frustrating for beginners.

Comment: @cel In my experience Anaconda/Conda solves the problem of broken packages. Just use Miniconda if you don't 200 packages. I work a lot with beginners and Anaconda made things so much easier.

Comment: I wish I could confirm that :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is complaining to the log file. If you can specify it it should solve the problem, as now it is not finding it.